# Remove lines with japanese characters from a file

Tags: linux, sed

First question on here- I've searched around to put together an answer to this but have come up empty thus far.

I have a multi-line text file that I am cleaning up. Part of this is to remove lines that include Japanese characters. I have been using `sed` for my other operations but it is not working in this instance.

I was under the impression that using the `-r` switch and the `\p{Han}` regular expression would work (from looking at other questions of this kind), but it is not working in this case.

Here is my test string - running this returns the full string, and does not filter out the JP characters as I was expecting.

```
echo 80岁返老还童的处女: 第3话 | sed -r "s/\\p\{Han\}//g"
```

Am I missing something? Is there another command I should be using instead?

Comment: do you know , you have other characters in your file except Japanese and acsii characters?

Comment: Yes. The file is a list of book titles scraped from Amazon, so there is a bit of a hodgepodge in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work for you:

```
echo "80岁返老还童的处女: 第3话" | tr -cd '[:print:]\n'
```

sed doesn't support unicode classes AFAIK, and nor support multibyte ranges.

`-d` deletes characters in SET1, and `-c` reverses it.
`[:print:]` matches all printable characters including space.
`\n` is a newline

The above will not only remove Japanese characters but all multibyte characters, including control characters.

Perl can also be used:

```
PERLIO=:utf8 perl -pe 's/\p{Han}//g' file
```

`PERLIO=:utf8` tells Perl to tread input and output as UTF-8

Comment: This is very, very close, thank you! How can I adjust the perl command to remove the whole line that contains the JP characters, not just those characters themselves? 
Like `sed "/thing/d"`

Comment: `perl -ne 'print unless /\p{Han}/'`. Note i changed `-p` to `-n`

Comment: This works, but I appear to have deeper problems with my workflow as the perl script chokes on my input with `Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal)`. I'm going to mark this as correct (as it is) and will fix these underlying issues.

Comment: `echo "岁返ＭＫ" | tr -cd '[:print:]\n'` prints nothing. While it expected to print `MK`. Any ideas?